# Powershell script output csv file restructure

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell scripts that runs and gets security permissions in a server and output these in a csv. At the moment its outputting the information but with each file it reads it is including the header Account, Ace String and Object Path again: how do i remove so it only shows it at the start of the document only?

**Account,Ace String,Object Path**
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,Allow FullControl,  (Inherited),C:\Users\munjanga\Documents\Operations Orchestration\jetty
BUILTIN\Administrators,Allow FullControl,  (Inherited),C:\Users\munjanga\Documents\Operations Orchestration\jetty
EMEA\munjanga,Allow FullControl,  (Inherited),C:\Users\munjanga\Documents\Operations Orchestration\jetty
**Account,Ace String,Object Path**
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,Allow FullControl,  (Inherited),C:\Users\munjanga\Documents\Operations Orchestration\jre1.6

```
    $OutFile = "C:\Users\munjanga\Documents\AoN Project\Execute\$([Environment]::MachineName).txt"  
$Header = "Folder Path,IdentityReference,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags,PropagationFlags"
Del $OutFile
Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $OutFile 

$RootPath = "C:\Users\munjanga\Documents\Operations Orchestration"

$Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}

$isInherited = @{
 $true  = 'Inherited'
 $false = 'Not Inherited'
}

$inheritance = @{
 0 = 'files only'
 1 = 'this folder and subfolders'
 2 = 'this folder and files'
  3 = 'subfolders and files'
}

$fldr = $Folder.FullName

$Folders | % {
$fldr = $_.FullName
Get-Acl $fldr | select -Expand Access |
 select @{n='Account';e={$_.IdentityReference}},
     @{n='Ace String';e={"{0} {1}, {2} ({3})" -f $_.AccessControlType,
       $_.FileSystemRights, $inheritance[$_.InheritanceFlags],
       $isInherited[$_.IsInherited]}},
    @{n='Object Path';e={$fldr}} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | Out-File $OutFile -Force -Encoding ascii -Append}
```

Comment: You're getting different headers from two different places at the moment. The `Add-Content` line is adding the `$Header` values at the top of the file, and then the `ConvertTo-Csv` is adding additional headers from `Get-Acl` and following. Do you want both? Or just the headers at the top?

Comment: I just want the header at the top of the file to stay, how do that? is it simply removing convertTocsv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see if this works:

```
@{n='Object Path';e={$fldr}} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select -Skip 1 | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | Out-File $OutFile -Force -Encoding ascii -Append
```

The key bit is the `Select -Skip 1` after the `ConvertTo-Csv` piece.

**Edit:**

After thinking this through a bit more there's a better answer here. The last line should look something like this:

```
@{n='Object Path';e={$fldr}}} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | Out-File $OutFile -Force -Encoding ascii -Append
```

That loop should be closed *before* converting to CSV.

Comment: okay so it gets rid of them but now for the headers it is showing:Folder Path,IdentityReference,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags,PropagationFlags instead of (folder, ace path and object path)

Comment: Right, that's being done by lines 2 and 4 in your code. If you want to change the headers you can edit the `$Headers` string in line 2.

Comment: thats has worked, but noww the " " marks have all come back in the file :(

Comment: its fine don't know the "" had come back, i re-ran it and now its fine